# How to let my Angular libraries use the Angular Material Theme of the root app?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

I'm using Angular Material Components like  inside my own Angular libraries. So far no problem. But is there a way so the libraries use the Angular Material Theming of the root app they are embedded in? The goal is to inherit the Theming of the root app for a consistent look & feel throughout the app.

One idea was to to add a reference to the theme stylesheet in my library component like this...
`@Component({selector: 'my-selector', templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html', styleUrls: '/path/to/the/theme/stylesheet', '...']})`
...or to import the theme stylesheet in the library component's stylesheet: `@import 'path/to/the/theme/stylesheet.scss'`
The downside to this is that you you have to know the paths in root app. If the path changes over time, the reference is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use APP_INITILIZER to set the path at application start-up and pass it as a provider.